# Base class pointer conversion

Tags: c++, pointers

The following code I've written to check pointer conversion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A
{ 
    friend class B;
};

class B : private A { };

int main()
{
    B *b = new B;
    A *a = b;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << a;
}
```

Section 11.2/4 N3797 says:

```
A base class B of N is accessible at R, if 
— an invented public member of B would be a public member of N, or 
— R occurs in a member or friend of class N, and an invented public member of B would be a private or protected member of N, or 
— R occurs in a member or friend of a class P derived from N, and an invented public member of B would be a private or protected member of P, or 
— there exists a class S such that B is a base class of S accessible at R and S is a base class of N accessible at R
```

I think `A` is accessible base class of `B`.

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base
>   class (Clause 10) of D. If B is an inaccessible (Clause 11) or
>   ambiguous (10.2) base class of D, a program that necessitates this
>   conversion is ill-formed

Why do I recieve a compile-time error?

```
main.cpp:17:12: error: cannot cast 'B' to its private base class 'A'
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09bcbd274c6b15c8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the `friend` declaration to make the conversion valid, it needs to take place in a scope where the friendship has effect -- that is, in `B`'s own code. The fact that `A` declares `B` as a friend has no effect outside `B`'s definition.

Comment: Would you explain what `R` means in the definition of _accessibility_.

Comment: `R` is the scope at which the conversion is attempted.

Comment: Hmm... It semms to be ok. But why do you think that R is a scope? I cannot find any definition of `R`.

Comment: Yeah, the Standard's often a little unclear about that sort of thing. But the phrase "at R" is locative; it implies that `R` is a place, rather than a thing. I'm not sure if `R` is a scope, an expression, or a statement, but I know it's not a class or object (because the standard never says that things are "at" an object or "at" a class).

Comment: @St.Antario: `R` is the point at which the conversion (and access to the base class) is attempted. In this case, that point is in `main`, which is not in a member or friend of `B`, and so the base class isn't accessible.

Comment: Incidentally, the fact that `R` is not explicitly defined is clearly a problem with the standard; you should report it to be addressed in a future version.

Comment: Indeed, I've added friend main function declartion into `B` and it works. Very very nice. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b60d2d5d350f35ac Thanks everyone :).